# Javascript I am trying to pause the ball with noloop(); but on key up I want to continue the ball bounce can you look at my code and help me?

Tags: javascript

Javascript I am trying to pause the ball with noloop(); but on key up I want to continue the ball bounce can you look at my code and help me?   I am having trouble trying to  pause the bouncing ball at frame-rate and return to bounce the ball. I managed to get some code that is able to identify at least a couple of keys, but I only need one key to stop the bouncing ball and the same key when release to let the ball bounce? Any ideas? Please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Player Movement using onkeydown/onkeyup (Enhanced version)</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
          canvas { border: 1px solid; }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var _gaq = _gaq || [];
          _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1150473-1']);
          _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

          (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
          })();
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


        var context;
    var x=100;
    var y=200;
    var dx=5;
    var dy=5;
        var Key = {
          _pressed: {},

          LEFT: 37,
          UP: 38,
          RIGHT: 39,
          DOWN: 40,

          isDown: function(keyCode) {
            return this._pressed[keyCode];
          },

          onKeydown: function(event) {
            this._pressed[event.keyCode] = true;
          },

          onKeyup: function(event) {
            delete this._pressed[event.keyCode];
          }
        };

        window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) { Key.onKeyup(event); }, false);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) { Key.onKeydown(event); }, false);

        var Game = {
          fps: 60,
          width: 640,
          height: 480
        };

        Game._onEachFrame = (function() {
          var requestAnimationFrame = window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

          if (requestAnimationFrame) {
           return function(cb) {
              var _cb = function() { cb(); requestAnimationFrame(_cb); }
              _cb();
            };
          } else {
            return function(cb) {
              setInterval(cb, 1000 / Game.fps);
            }
          }
        })();

        Game.start = function() {
          Game.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
          Game.canvas.width = Game.width;
          Game.canvas.height = Game.height;

          Game.context = Game.canvas.getContext("2d");

          document.body.appendChild(Game.canvas);

          Game.player = new Player();

          Game._onEachFrame(Game.run);
        };

        Game.run = (function() {
          var loops = 0, skipTicks = 1000 / Game.fps,
              maxFrameSkip = 10,
              nextGameTick = (new Date).getTime(),
              lastGameTick;

          return function() {
            loops = 0;

            while ((new Date).getTime() > nextGameTick) {
              Game.update();
              nextGameTick += skipTicks;
              loops++;
            }

            if (loops) Game.draw();
          }
        })();

        Game.draw = function() {
          Game.context.clearRect(0, 0, Game.width, Game.height);
          Game.player.draw(Game.context);
        };

        Game.update = function() {
          Game.player.update();
        };

        function Player() {
          this.x = 0;
          this.y = 0;
        }

        Player.prototype.draw = function(context) {
          context.clearRect(0,0, 300,300);
      context.beginPath();
      context.fillStyle="#0000ff";
      //Draw a circle of radius 20 at the coordinates 100,100 on the canvas
      context.arc(this.x, this.y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true); 
      context.closePath();
      context.fill(); 
      if(this.x<0 || this.x>550) dx=-dx;
      if(this.y<0 || this.y>400) dy=-dy;
      this.x+=dx;
      this.y+=dy;
      //noLoop();
        };

        Player.prototype.moveLeft = function() {
          this.x = 100;
          this.y = 100;
        };

        Player.prototype.moveRight = function() {
          //if (onKeyup) noloop();
          //else if (onKeydown) loops();

        };

        Player.prototype.moveUp = function() {
          this.y -= 1;
        };

        Player.prototype.moveDown = function() {
          this.y += 1;
        };

        Player.prototype.update = function() {
          if (Key.isDown(Key.UP)) this.moveUp();
          if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) this.moveLeft();
          if (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN)) this.moveDown();
          if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)) this.moveRight();
          //else if (Key.onKeyup(Key.RIGHT)) this.Loop();



        };
        </script>
      </head>
      <body onload="Game.start()">
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I'm kind of confused by your question. What is "noloop"? I don't see it defined in the scope of your code. It might also help to post a jsfiddle with your code running. I went ahead and made one for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/a5y141zv/1/

Comment: Well as you can see in line on line 113 of the code I wanted to debug and identify if the noLoop() function worked and it did. However, I just wanted to code the left key to stop the ball from bouncing and then once the key is let go to return the bouncing ball. I am running into blocks because I don't know how to do that especially with the code. I have other elemen keys that I will code later but I just need to lear to code the left key to stop the bounce and once the key is let go to bounce again. I was able to code a coordinate which gives the illusion of stop but it is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out with the help of prof. Hovland that the code just needs to be tested and debugged by breaking it. Looking at the sequence there is a loops method that has a value associated with it, and when changing the value the loop sequence stalls and is able to return back once the key is presses comments will be posted later

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Player Movement using onkeydown/onkeyup (Enhanced version)</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      canvas { border: 1px solid; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1150473-1']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var nextGameTick = (new Date).getTime();
var isPaused = 0;
var loops = 0;
var context;
var x=100;
var y=200;
var dx=5;
var dy=5;
    var Key = {
      _pressed: {},

      LEFT: 37,
      UP: 38,
      RIGHT: 39,
      DOWN: 40,

      isDown: function(keyCode) {
        return this._pressed[keyCode];
      },

      onKeydown: function(event) {
        this._pressed[event.keyCode] = true;
      },

      onKeyup: function(event) {
        delete this._pressed[event.keyCode];
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) { Key.onKeyup(event); }, false);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) { Key.onKeydown(event); }, false);

    var Game = {
      fps: 60,
      width: 640,
      height: 480
    };

    Game._onEachFrame = (function() {
      var requestAnimationFrame = window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

      if (requestAnimationFrame) {
       return function(cb) {
          var _cb = function() { cb(); requestAnimationFrame(_cb); }
          _cb();
        };
      } else {
        return function(cb) {
          setInterval(cb, 1000 / Game.fps);
        }
      }
    })();

    Game.start = function() {
      Game.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      Game.canvas.width = Game.width;
      Game.canvas.height = Game.height;

      Game.context = Game.canvas.getContext("2d");

      document.body.appendChild(Game.canvas);

      Game.player = new Player();

      Game._onEachFrame(Game.run);
    };

    Game.run = (function() {
      var    
        skipTicks = 1000 / Game.fps,
        maxFrameSkip = 10,
        //nextGameTick = (new Date).getTime(),
        lastGameTick,
        tempTick;
      return function() {
        loops = 0;
    tempTick = (new Date).getTime();

        if ( tempTick > nextGameTick) {
          Game.update();
          nextGameTick += skipTicks;
          loops++;
        }




        if (loops > 0) Game.draw();
    else    {
            console.log("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        }
      }
    })();

    Game.draw = function() {
      Game.context.clearRect(0, 0, Game.width, Game.height);
      Game.player.draw(Game.context);
    };

    Game.update = function() {
      Game.player.update();
    };

    function Player() {
      this.x = 0;
      this.y = 0;
    }

    Player.prototype.draw = function(context) {
      context.clearRect(0,0, 300,300);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle="#0000ff";
  //Draw a circle of radius 20 at the coordinates 100,100 on the canvas
  context.arc(this.x, this.y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true); 
  context.closePath();
  context.fill(); 
  if(this.x<0 || this.x>550) dx=-dx;
  if(this.y<0 || this.y>400) dy=-dy;
  this.x+=dx;
  this.y+=dy;
  //noLoop();
    };

    Player.prototype.moveLeft = function() {
    loops = -12;

   // if(isPaused == 0){
//  loops = -1;
//  isPaused = 1;
//  console.log("paused");
//  }
//  else if(isPaused == 1){
//  loops = 1;
//  isPaused = 0;
//  console.log("unpaused");
//  }

    };

Player.prototype.notMoveLeft = function() {
  console.log("left arrow up");
    //Game.run();
    };

    Player.prototype.moveRight = function() {
     console.log("Foo");
      //if (onKeyup) noloop();
      //else if (onKeydown) loops();

    };

    Player.prototype.moveUp = function() {
      this.y -= 1;
    };

    Player.prototype.moveDown = function() {
      this.y += 1;
    };

    Player.prototype.update = function() {
      if (Key.isDown(Key.UP)) this.moveUp();
      if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) this.moveLeft();
      if (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN)) this.moveDown();
      if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)) this.moveRight();
      if (Key.onKeyup(Key.LEFT)) this.notMoveLeft();



    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="Game.start()">
  </body>
</html>
```